# How to create a report in TFS (Excel) to blend data from Task and parent User Story?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs

We have a customized template in TFS 2010 where we basically store some common data in a user Story item and then more details in the various tasks. All tasks are linked to a parent user story and only one parent link exists.

What we need to get out is a table of information from the user story and task on the same row, like this:

US Title, Task Assigned to, US Effort, Task Hours Remaining etc.

Is this possible and how would I go about to do it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Excel pivot to achieve this kind of (probably not what you want).

Another option is to create a SSRS report or Excel report based on T-SQL that queries the Tfs_Warehouse database.

Comment: Thanx. But the database is actually called TFS_Reporting in my installation. But I made it all work.